# How to shuffle a matrix and an array accordingly

Tags: python, list, numpy, shuffle

Suppose I have an `mXd` matrix called `X`, and an `mX1` array called `Y` (using `numpy`). The rows of `X` correspond to the rows of `Y`.

Now suppose I need to shuffle the data (the rows) in `X`. I used:

```
random.shuffle(X)
```

Is there a way for me to keep track of the way `X` has been shuffled, so I could shuffle `Y` accordingly?

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you actually want or shuffle the columns of Y ?

Comment: I want to shuffle the rows of X, and as the rows of X correspond to the rows of Y, I would like to shuffle Y as well...

Comment: what you mean by *correspond* ? whats the logic behind this corresponding >?

Comment: Try to shuffle a index matrix, and then use that index matrix to recreate x and y

Comment: @Kasra - It's machine learning stuff - the X is for data instances and the Y's are the tags. So each row in Y _belongs_ to a row in X. I can't loose track of which tag belongs to which data instance.

Comment: @M4rtini - can you please elaborate?

Comment: basicly what @mdml just did in his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.random.permutation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) to create a permuted list of `indices`, and then shuffle both `X` and `Y`using those `indices`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> m = 10
>>> X = numpy.random.rand(m, m)
>>> Y = numpy.random.rand(m)
>>> indices = numpy.random.permutation(m)
>>> indices
array([4, 7, 6, 9, 0, 3, 1, 2, 8, 5])
>>> Y
array([ 0.53867012,  0.6700051 ,  0.06199551,  0.51248468,  0.4990566 ,
        0.81435935,  0.16030748,  0.96252029,  0.44897724,  0.98062564])
>>> Y = Y[indices]
>>> Y
array([ 0.4990566 ,  0.96252029,  0.16030748,  0.98062564,  0.53867012,
        0.51248468,  0.6700051 ,  0.06199551,  0.44897724,  0.81435935])
>>> X = X[indices, :]
```